# usage of naive bayes Model for prediction

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, naivebayes

Hi all I am new to scala and spark MLIB.

I have a dataset of diseses of diseases along with the symptoms which are in the following format:

Disease,symptom1 symptom2 symptom3

I have almost 300 entries which are in the above mentioned format in a CSV file.

I want to achieve this following functionality:

If a user has given a input of sysmptoms namely Symptom1,Symptom2,Symptom3 the model must be able to predict the disease.

I have the following Questions:

1. which machine learning model should I use to achieve this functionality.
2. I have gone through some models and founf NAIVES Bayes model if wrong correct me.
3. can I provide text input to Naives Bayes model.
4. Is there any sample code available to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the classification algorithms present in Spark MLlib for further reference read the official docs and go thru this link from databricks blog https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/29/new-features-in-machine-learning-pipelines-in-spark-1-4.html